# how to unbrick my ONN TVbox 100026240 (dopinder)

Tags: github, android-tv, firmware, android-firmware, tvbox

my ONN TVbox 100026240 dopinder got bricked after blackout.

my ONN TVbox 100026240 dopinder got bricked after blackout. I conected the equipment succesfully using amlogic USB burning tool but seems to be imposible to burn an image because the tvbox don´t allow to write unless is the original firmware. i tried to use de sabrina unlock xploit but i am not very sure how to use it on a VM (i only have a virtual ununtu machine on virtual vox) and also i don´t have too much knowledge using other OS than windows. Please help, is a really personal challenge and cannot afford a new tvbox system in a wile

UPDATE 30/05/2023

I finally was able to run the script of Sabrina unlock xploit but i have another problem... the device seems to be password protected. [unlock.sh error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IF8g.png)

using only fastboot is not an option the device not appear to be connected using fastboot nor adb.

but sabrina script and the device is readable by others means.

device name on ubuntu is amlogic GX-CHIP and on windows for some reason is called worldcup device

Answer (score 0):

1. connect ONN TV box to USB on a computer
2. fastboot flash all img files from your rom

This should help you get started:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201212/how-can-i-reboot-into-recovery-from-fastboot

Comment: cannot be recognice on fastboot as a divice but i manage to run the sabrina unlock script but the script showme that the device is protected by password.